# ros java client only

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to just build and use just a ros java messaging client - do I need to build the entire rosjava_core?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45335/ros-java-client-only/) by [antoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/3343/antoine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-10-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A "messaging client" isn't as simple as you might think. While you may be able to strip out some parts, I believe you'll want to use the whole rosjava_core.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1